# Прекращена работа программы имярек.exe

Tags: c, функции, указатели, рекурсия

Оно запускается, я ввожу число, и после этого появляется "Прекращена работа программы имя.exe". Почему так может быть?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void func(double* sum, double* argum, int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        *argum = *argum * k + 1. / k;
        *sum += *argum;
    } else func(&sum, &argum, k - 1);

    *argum = *argum * k + 1. / k;
    *sum += *argum;
}

double fun(int k) {
    int i;
    double s = 1.0;
    double a = 1.0;

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        a = a * i + 1.0 / i;
        s = s + a;
    }

    return s;
}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");

    int k;
    double a = 1.0;
    double s = 1.0;

    printf("Введите число: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    func(&s, &a, k);
    printf("Рекурсивно: %f\nНе рекурсивно: %f\n", s, fun(k));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эм.. Как оно вообще скомпилировалось? о_О

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, когда вы рекурсивно вызываете

```
func(&sum, &argum, k-1);
```

то вы передаете адреса локальных переменных, а не исходно переданные адреса. Так что первое - меняем на

```
func(sum, argum, k-1);
```

Замечу, что я даже особо не искал - компилятор сам выбросил предупреждение о неприятностях в этом месте. Никогда не игнорируйте никакие предупреждения компилятора!

Что именно оно считает, и верно ли - это уже вопрос совсем второй...

Comment: ооо, спасибо, теперь такого нет. считает, правда, неправильно, но это и правда другой вопрос.